# irregular / custom shaped ImageButton for Android

Tags: android, user-interface, transparent, imagebutton, viewgroup

I'd like to create irregularly shaped image buttons for Android, based on the transparent areas of the button image.

Basically, if you click on the transparent area of a button, instead of handling the event, it should propagate it 'down' to the views beneath itself. So if you overlap two of these buttons, you can actually click the `'bottom'` one (overlapped by `'top'`), if you click on a transparent area of `'top'` but a non-transparent area of `'bottom'`.

A working solution based on the same principle for iOS is e.g. OBShapedButton http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/obshapedbutton

---

My first idea was to create an `ImageButton` subclass (`CustomShapedButton`) to achieve this functionality. The following code can be used to determine if you clicked on a transparent are or not, given the actual drawable state and a `MotionEvent`.

```
public class CustomShapedButton extends ImageButton {
[...]

    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
    {
        // click coordinates of (MotionEvent e)
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();

        // get current state of drawable and the color under the click
        StateListDrawable s = (StateListDrawable)this.getBackground();
        int color = ((BitmapDrawable)s.getCurrent()).getBitmap().getPixel((int)x, (int)y);

        Log.d(TAG, "custom shaped button clicked at x: "+x+" y: "+y+" with color: "+color);

        if (color != 0)
        {
            // normal region clicked, should count as click
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            // transparent region clicked, should NOT count as click
            // ...
        }
    }

[...]
}
```

Where should I put the code above for the correct functionality? I tried to override the `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` and the `public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` methods, but with no luck (maybe I just didn't find the correct return values for each cases).

Based on the Android API docs, `public boolean interceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` looks like a possible solution for this type of behaviour, but it's defined in the `ViewGroup` class, thus cannot be used for an `ImageView` subclass.

Please respond, if you have experience with handling/propatating touch events and know the answer for my question!

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems with controlling touches. My solution was to extend a WebView so that it handled its own touches. I have done the same thing with a big TextView as well. You can find the source for the first one in this zipfile:

http://this-voice.org/dnlds/MoDaBrowserGNU.zip

As for buttons, I don't know if this will help. But I have had different results with putting an image on a regular Button than I do with an ImageButton. You might find something there that meets your need. Also, perhaps you've tried this, but you can put one button over another using margins in the XML. As for passing a press down, you would have to intercept the press coordinates in something like my WebView solution and "simulate" the overlap. I use quotes because all this stuff is simulation, right? Go for making the user feel like he's doing what you want him to experience. It doesn't matter what is under the hood.